# How to remove an item from an observableArray of observable objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a very large observable array, and each item in that array is an observable. I'm trying to remove an item from the observable array, but since each item in the array is observable `myArray.remove(item)` doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to remove the item without converting the whole array to non-observables, removing the item, and then repopulating the observable array? It feels like I'm missing something simple/obvious...

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201010/remove-from-observablearray-knockoutjs

Answer (score 0):

Try using myArray.remove(item())

---

I had the same problem and this is my solution

self.images() is an observablearray of observable image

So you can loop on your myArray to find the item and than remove it.

```
$.each(self.images(), function (index, value) {
                if (value.id_image() == id_image) {
                    self.images.remove(value);
                    return false; ;
                }
            });
```

Comment: `item` isn't an observable, so I don't think that will work. `item` is a standard object, and I want to remove it's observable instance in the array